Why does the curve appear like this?

I used the following code:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{ffqqqq}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{qqttzz}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0,0.39215686274509803,0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-5.5699999999999905,
xmax=6.310000000000031,
ymin=-2.5650000000000546,
ymax=5.974999999999941,
xtick={-5,-4,...,6},
ytick={-2,-1,...,5},]
\clip(-5.57,-2.565) rectangle (6.31,5.975);
\draw[line width=2pt,color=qqwuqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-5.5699999999999905:6.310000000000031] plot(\x,{((\x)^(2)+(\x)-3)/((\x)^(2)+(\x)-2)});
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqttzz] (-2,-2.565) -- (-2,5.975);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqttzz] (1,-2.565) -- (1,5.975);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffqqqq,domain=-5.57:6.31] plot(\x,{(--1-0*\x)/1});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (2.4,0.5) node {$( C_{f}  )$};
\draw[color=ffqqqq] (4,1.405) node {$( D )$};
\draw[color=qqttzz] (2,0.5) node {};
\draw[color=qqttzz] (0.91,5.725) node {};

\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

But the curve came out like the one in the attached image!

Are you asking about the fact that your curve seems to jump across vertical asymptotes? PGFPlots is simply taking 100 samples of x-values across the domain that you told it to use, then substituting those into your function. Because the domain has gaps at x = −2 and x = 1, PGFPlots simply tries to connect the dots between the side where y approaches infinity, and the side where y approaches negative infinity. You'll need to specify each continuous subset of your domain on separate plots if you don't want to simply connect the dots.

By the way, because you're using PGFPlots, you can use \addplot instead of Tikz's \draw plot. You might want to check this out to simplify the process of graphing :)

did you write this by hand?  or was it generated by some software?

@Thruston Given that some other recent questions show a lot similar strange code, e.g. the unnecessary \clip, the just-works-by-chance \begin{scriptsize}...\end{scriptsize}, I would assume some not-so-good tool produces such tikz code.

@Thurston I used GeoGebra

@gz839918 In GeoGebra the drawing appears normally, but in Latex the drawing appears distorted.

@mlc The TikZ code produced by GeoGebra is usually quite bad and always needs editing.

With some editing to the GeoGebra generated code, which should always be done, I get
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{ffqqqq}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{qqttzz}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
  x=1cm,y=1cm,
  axis lines=middle,
  ymajorgrids=true,
  xmajorgrids=true,
  xmin=-5.57,
  xmax=6.31,
  ymin=-2.565,
  ymax=5.975,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,6},
  ytick={-2,-1,...,5},]
  %\clip(-5.57,-2.565) rectangle (6.31,5.975);
  \draw[
    line width=0.4pt,
    color=qqwuqq,
    smooth,
    samples=1000,
    domain=-5.57:6.31
  ] plot(\x,{((\x)^(2)+(\x)-3)/((\x)^(2)+(\x)-2)});
  \draw [line width=0.4pt,color=qqttzz] (-2,-2.565) -- (-2,5.975);
  \draw [line width=0.4pt,color=qqttzz] (1,-2.565) -- (1,5.975);
  \draw [line width=0.4pt,color=ffqqqq,domain=-5.57:6.31] plot(\x,{(--1-0*\x)/1});
  %\begin{scriptsize}
  \draw[color=qqwuqq] (2.4,0.5) node {$( C_{f}  )$};
  \draw[color=ffqqqq] (4,1.405) node {$( D )$};
  \draw[color=qqttzz] (2,0.5) node {};
  \draw[color=qqttzz] (0.91,5.725) node {};

  %\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I rounded the nonsensical values with so many decimal digits and increased the number of samples, because 100 is too small.
Other changes: 0.4pt for the line thickness instead of 2pt; removed scriptsize that makes no sense and \clip.


OT: s/unsensical/nonsensical/  (con molte scuse perché il suo inglese è quasi perfetto)

@Thruston Thanks! :-)
